# Apache camel netty (udp server) not able to keep up with udp traffic

Tags: networking, udp, apache-camel, netty, nio

I am using apache netty module to receive udp packets.

Under load it does not seem to accept all sent udp packets.
I tested it by running a dummy udp server (non-camel, just counts number of received packets) and sent 1000 packets per second  from localhost, this dummy udp server accepted and counted all. However sending 1000 packets per second from localhost to my camel udp port, I can see that some (1-5%) never show up.

What camel netty configuration should I play with to resolve this issue?

BTW I am sending udp packets in tight loop

Update: I am now providing following default threadProfile.

```
    <threadPoolProfile id="myDefaultProfile"
                       defaultProfile="true"
                       poolSize="20"
                       keepAliveTime="25"
                       maxPoolSize="50"
                       maxQueueSize="100000"/>
```

Still get packet loss.

Comment: Not that this helps with your problem, but: With UDP you have to be able to deal with packet loss. UDP does not provide reliable transport.

Comment: Ack. But I am trying to compare apples with apples (non-camel udp receiver with camel-netty udp receiver) and getting packet loss in camel-netty but not the other. It might be due to camel-netty using NIO and other one using Java IO.